# Remove Duplicate Data in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sorry  a new-bie SQL question here ,I have the a DB containing data in a similar form

```
 U1 Program_Id  A_ID    Date
 x1    A         1       1
 x1    A         2       1
 x1    A         3       1
 x1    B         1       1
 x1    B         2       1
 x1    B         3       1
 x2    B         1       1
 x2    B         2       1
```

I would like to de duplicate the data considering all the four columns ,such that my final output will be like below

```
U1  Program_Id  A_ID    Date
x1  A        1       1
x1  A        2       1
x1  A        3       1
x2  B        1       1
x2  B        2       1
```

ie `X1 A` exists and `X1 B` also exist ,for the same Date hence those are duplicates that need to be removed , keeping just `X1 A` rows , `X1 B` rows are the duplicates here.

Comment: Just to be clear, shouldn't `x2 B 3 1` also be in the output?

Comment: If so, try running `SELECT DISTINCT U1, JOBID, A_ID, DATE FROM YOUR_TABLE; `

Comment: @Vashi:No , x2 B 3 1 is not in the input too

Comment: so, what about three rows for x1 B ... ? why they are not in output? you should provide more details about your logic

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant : Yes you are right , sorry ,my ignorance , X1 A exists  and X1 b also exist ,for the same Date hence those are duplicates that need to be removed.

Comment: so, what is the logic that determine dups? is it combination of U1, A_ID and Date? and if so, what the logic to pick A over B? Think through your use case and update your question respectively

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant : Yes updated :)

Comment: what is the logic behind `keeping just X1 A rows , X1 B rows are the duplicates here.`? what if there will be B and C for another day? C survive or none (because of absence of A)? please do not rush - just think through all such possible questions

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant : There wont be any a C in the Data only A's and B's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT U1, MIN(Program_Id) Program_Id, A_ID, DATE
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY U1, A_ID, DATE
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'x1' U1, 'A' Program_Id, 1 A_ID, 1 DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x1', 'A', 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x1', 'A', 3, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x1', 'B', 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x1', 'B', 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x1', 'B', 3, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x2', 'B', 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x2', 'B', 2, 1 
)
SELECT U1, MIN(Program_Id) Program_Id, A_ID, DATE
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY U1, A_ID, DATE
ORDER BY DATE, U1, A_ID
```

result is

```
U1  Program_Id  A_ID    DATE     
x1  A           1       1    
x1  A           2       1    
x1  A           3       1    
x2  B           1       1    
x2  B           2       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .The query works perfectly fine for a particular date , but cannot generalize it over dates

Comment: if you have follow up questions  - please post them as separate question(s) and we will be happy to answer them Meantime, the current question is answered and I tried to make all possible to force you to think generically (see question's comments). Hope this post will further help you in tuning and defining your requirements - so your next question will be much better!

Comment: Also, below links can help you for next questions - [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: Really appreciate your help :)  ,i think i got the query to work over multiple dates by removing the A_ID from the groupby , let me think deep like you said. If you have intuitions as of why ,please do .