# Comparing multiple large data sets for duplicates in bigquery

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, google-bigquery, soql

I have limited experience with soql for salesforce and need to apply that to this issue in bigquery.

Context: 
I have 4 different datasets with dissimilar column names and order ranging from 7000 to 35000 rows all four contain duplicate rows within themselves and duplicates are shared between them.

Goal: 
I want a single dataset with no duplicate rows.

My Intuition:
I feel like I should normalize the column names add them all the same table and take this approach [Remove Duplicate Data in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702120/remove-duplicate-data-in-bigquery)

At the same time I feel like it maybe better to upload each dataset to its own table and use joins or something to write to a new table. I really have no experience in this area to make an educated decision.

I chose bigquery soley because I have access to it if there is a better solution I am open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union`:

```
select a as x, b as y, c as z
from table1
union distinct
select d, e, f
from table2
union distinct
select g, h, i
from table3
union distinct
select j, k, l
from table4;
```

`union` removes duplicates both within tables and between tables.  This will return columns with the names `x`, `y`, and `z`.